# I can install Ubuntu Minimal with wifi?

Tags: system-installation, ubuntu-minimal

I want to install Ubuntu Minimal in dualboot on my Ideapad S145, but I have no ethernet cable input.

Because of this I would like to know if I can install Ubuntu Minimal using a Wi-Fi connection only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot install Ubuntu Minimal with Wi-Fi, unless you do some advanced tweaking. So if you are just a beginner, I recommend the normal installation, since it contains everything you need. Besides, the normal Ubuntu version only takes about 13 GB in space (size may vary).

Comment: can't you connect to wifi at installation? It asked me to when I installed mate18.04

Comment: Oh Yeah, in installation you can connect to wifi, but when you get to the os, poof

Comment: reconnect to wifi?